# AngularJS ui-router v1.0.14 - Child states load first time, then disappear on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having a difficult time understanding why my child states don't work properly. What I'm trying to do is define a parent abstract state ("queues") which defines the base-url, and then three child states to show three different types based on a parameter. Here is what I have:

```
/* Queues */
        .state('queues', {
            abstract: true,
            parent: 'app',
            url: '/queues',
            template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'
        })
            .state('queues.user', {
                url: '/user/{userId:int}',
                component: 'userQueue'
            })
            .state('queues.request', {
                url: '/request/{queue}',
                component: 'requestQueue'
            })
            .state('queues.function', {
                url: '/group/{function}',
                component: 'functionGroupQueue'
            })
```

This works the first time I go to any of the child states, however, if I try to change the parameters, or go to a sibling state, the child template AND the parent  is taken out of the HTML and never reinserted.

First time visiting 'queues.request' state with $stateParams.queue = 'all':

[First visit to 'queues.request' state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYZwP.png)

Then what happens after visiting any sibling state or changing state parameters:

[Transition to sibling state or changed parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0uhN.png)

Strange.

I can make it work by not nesting the states, and simply making them their own individual states, however, I would really like to know why the above way doesn't work properly.

Any help would be appreciated.